# Using powershell, how to I resend messages from Dead Letter queue to regular queue?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Id like to use powershell alone to move messages which have been placed onto the dead letter queue onto a different regular queue. How can I accomplish this with powershell alone?

I realize I can accomplish this with a GUI such as Service Bus Explorer. But I need a scripted approach. 
I also see that there is a chance I can accomplish this in c# as shown 
http://www.anderbakk.com/resend-dead-letters-from-an-azure-service-bus-queue/

Is c# the only viable approach here? It seems like a potentially common request.

Comment: As a workaround, you can directly import the necessary dll of servicebus in your powershell script, then use the methods in the dll.

Comment: no cmdlets available for this?

Comment: I didn't find one.

Comment: I mean, I understand I can simply wrap c# in a powershell module, and within a cmdlet myself simply wrap the c# code above. But I suppose I was hoping for something prebuilt.

Comment: @Judy007 did you ever come up with something? Had the same problem, and was told to use the SDK, there's no Cmdlets for it. Thanks!